# Execute function on scroll js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Please tell me how can I execute the function when the document `scroll` is equal to the position of the `#footer` element?

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var s = $(this).scrollTop();
  var scroll_footer = $('#footer').position().top;
  $("#console").text(s + " " + scroll_footer);
  if (s >= scroll_footer) {
    console.log("load");
  }
});
```

```css
#block {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
}

#child_block {
  padding-top: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 15px 10px 10px;
  15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
}

#console {
  position: fixed;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
  <div id="child_block">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
    <div class="child">7</div>
    <div class="child">8</div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
<div id="console"></div>
```

Comment: Use [Intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a `pageHeight` variable to your JS, so you're now calculating the window height in pixels + the amount the client has scrolled. When these two values >= `scroll_footer`, your function can execute.

```
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var s = $(this).scrollTop();
  var pageHeight = window.innerHeight
  var scroll_footer = $('#footer').position().top;
  $("#console").text((s+pageHeight) + " " + scroll_footer);
  if (s+pageHeight >= scroll_footer) {
    console.log("load");
  }
});
```

Here's a working codepen:
https://codepen.io/paulmartin91/pen/dyNwJmp?editors=1111